# How can I make the website theme persists on refresh in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm currently working in a weather forecast website and I'm trying to apply a theme toggler. I have already set up the functionality, but the chosen theme does not persist when the page is refreshed. Could anyone point out what I'm missing? The console.log shows that the theme inside localStorage changes when I click the theme toggler.

```
import { WeatherApi } from "./pages/home/weather-api";
import '../src/App.scss'
import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactSwitch from "react-switch";

export const ThemeContext = createContext({})

function App() {

  const [theme, setTheme] = useState<string>(localStorage.getItem('theme') || 'light')

  useEffect(() => {

    const localTheme = localStorage.getItem(theme)
    console.log(localTheme)

    if (!localTheme) {
      setTheme("light")
    }

    if (localTheme) {
      if (localTheme === 'light') {
        setTheme('light')
        localStorage.setItem('theme', theme)
        console.log(localStorage)
      }

      if (localTheme === 'dark') {
        setTheme('dark')
        localStorage.setItem('theme', theme)
        console.log(localStorage)
      }
    }
  },[theme])

  const toggleTheme = () => {
    setTheme((currentTheme: any) => (currentTheme === "light" ? "dark" : "light"))
  }

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, toggleTheme }}>
      <div className="App" id={theme}>
        <WeatherApi />
        <div className="switch">
          <label>{theme === "light" ? "Light mode" : "Dark mode"}</label>
          <ReactSwitch onChange={toggleTheme} checked={theme === "dark"} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  )

}

export default App;
```

Comment: You should set an initial state loading from localStorage, something like `const [theme, setTheme] = useState<string>(localStorage.getItem('theme') || 'light')` ;

Comment: Not exactly your problem but why are you JSON encoding a plain string?

Comment: `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` are not necessary, you are using `string`. They are only necessary if you are using `object`.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I edited my question with the suggested information, but it is still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: use `localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light')` and `localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark')` perhaps instead of `localStorage.setItem('theme', theme)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already load the theme from `localStorage` as the default value of the state. The other load from `localStorage` in `useEffect` is probably discarding/overriding user changes.

Try removing it. For example:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);
  }, [theme]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should load the theme from localStorage and use it as initialState, something like this:

```js
///... more js code
  const intialState = localStorage.getItem('theme') || 'light');
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState<string>('')

  const toggleTheme = () => {
    const newTheme = theme === "light" ? "dark" : "light";
    localStorage.setItem('theme', newTheme);
    setTheme(newTheme);
  }
///... more js code
```

Note: you don't need to use JSON.stringify or JSON.parse in strings

Answer (score 1):

You've got a classic *effect hook infinite loop* here. The effect hook has a dependency on `theme`. If you call `setTheme` inside the hook, it will re-run ad infinitum.

I would recommend creating a theme context provider component like this. Since you're using Typescript, you should avoid `any` and properly type all your values.

```tsx
import { createContext, useState, useEffect, FC } from "react";

type Theme = "light" | "dark";

interface ThemeContextValue {
  theme: Theme;
  toggleTheme: () => void;
}

export const ThemeContext = createContext<ThemeContextValue>({
  theme: "light",
  toggleTheme: () => {},
});

export const ThemeContextProvider: FC = ({ children }) => {
  // initialise state from localStorage
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState<Theme>(
    (localStorage.getItem("theme") ?? "light") as Theme
  );

  // update localStorage when the theme changes
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("theme", theme);
  }, [theme]);

  const toggleTheme = () => {
    setTheme((current) => (current === "light" ? "dark" : "light"));
  };

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, toggleTheme }}>
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};
```